# For a structure A, why is Th(A) a complete theory

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let's say you have a structure $A$ of some language and a set of all sentences that are true in such structure $Th(A)$ of the same language.

Then $Th(A)$ is supposedly a complete theory. I fully believe that $A$ is a model of $Th(A)$ but have hard time understanding why should it be the only one.

I mean, why can't we have a structure $B$ in which all $Th(A)$ sentences are true but where one additional sentence is true. Then it would still be a model of $Th(A)$ (as $Th(A)$ is subset of $Th(B)$) which means $Th(A)$ wouldn't be a complete theory (it would have two non-equivalent models).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be any sentence of the language $L$, and let $A$ be an $L$-structure. Then one of $\varphi$ or $\lnot\varphi$ is true in $A$. Hence $\text{Th}(A)$ is complete.

We look in particular at your structure $B$. Let $\psi$ be the "additional" sentence of $L$ which is true in $B$. If $\psi$ was not true in $A$, then $\lnot\psi$ was true in $A$, so is an axiom of $\text{Th}(A)$. Since $B$ is a model of $\text{Th}(A)$, it follows that $\psi$ cannot be true in $B$.

It is perfectly possible by *extending* $L$ to a new language $L'$, to produce a new sentence $\psi$ and an $L'$-structure $B$ in which $\psi$ is true. But this can only be done with a sentence that is not a sentence of $L$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the "Hence" part and how exactly does it counter my argument in 3rd paragraph? I mean, I believe that it works the way you wrote it but I'd very much prefer to understand why and all implications of it.

Comment: Ok, understand it now. Thanks :)!

Comment: @Petrroll: You are welcome. I hope the added material helps. In principle the first paragraph is enough, since a theory is by definition complete iff for any $\varphi$ of the language, one of $\varphi$ or $\lnot\varphi$ is a theorem.

Comment: Just as a footnote, it *is* possible to have $Th(A) = Th(B)$ for two nonisomorphic models $A, B$ — for example, if both are models of a complete theory, such as real closed fields. First order logic can't characterize the cardinality of models (by the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem), so $A$ an $B$ might even have different sizes.

Comment: This statement has always confused me: "Then one of $\varphi$ or $\lnot\varphi$ is true in $A$." Is there some implicit platonism going on here preventing $\varphi$ from being independent of $A$? (Are we abandoning formal proof?)

Comment: @AndréNicolas why can you say that either $\varphi$ or $\neg \varphi$ is true in $A$? I think that this is the point of the question.